# Sitemap generation of react app integrated in laravel using react-snap

Tags: sitemap, xml-sitemap, react-snap, react-laravel

I am using react.js integrated in laravel and when I make a postbuild using react snap it is showing me errors that the pages are not found.

What I have is I have app.blade.php in my resources/views which serves as public/index.html and app.jsx in my resources/js which serves as src/index.js.

When i try to make a postbuild it is showing me errors of missing files in the specifies locations.

Missing index.html in public, missing index.js in src.

Please let me know how can I fix this issue.

I have tried all the available configurations of react-snap package.